# android object animator transition and alpahn

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to animate the fragment transition, I successfully animate the transition but I also need that at the same time makes a fade out or in with alpha.
This is my code:

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment frag, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

   fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_from_left, 
   R.animator.exit_from_right, R.animator.enter_from_right, 
   R.animator.exit_from_left);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, frag, tag);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

This are the animators:

This is the enter from left:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="450"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="1000"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType"/>
</set>
```

This is the enter from right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="450"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="1000"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType"/>
</set>
```

This is the exit from left:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="450"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1000"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
</set>
```

This is the exit from right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="450"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="-1000"
    android:valueType="floatType"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify multiple animator objects inside the  tag defined in your xml and can also specify their ordering weather to be played together or sequentially.

here's how you can change your xml to achieve what you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false"
android:ordering="together">

<objectAnimator
    android:duration="450"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="1000"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType"/>

 <objectAnimator
    android:duration="450"
    android:valueFrom="0f"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:valueTo="1f" />
```

Comment: Great... Please accept the answer so that others can be benefited.